# Remotely run .exe in Azure Virtual Machine from ASP.Net web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, console-application, azure-virtual-machine

I have created a C# console app that runs on an Azure virtual machine. The problem is this needs to be executed by a user from a web app because the timing of the data pull is restricted to a narrow window and is somewhat random (at the moment I am going on to the virtual machine and running it myself).

So, in short, I would like to be able to make a call to an Azure Virtual Machine from an ASP.Net web app, also hosted in Azure. I also would like to pass in a parameter to that .exe file and get it to run.

Comment: Is there a shared database between the two at all? If so you could look into using something like [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/) to trigger a task in the console app. Failing that you might look into something like message queues e.g. [Azure Service Bus](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/service-bus/) to trigger the task to run. Both are relatively simple to achieve depending on your circumstances.

Answer (score 3):

We implemented the similar functionality by using Azure WebJobs.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-get-started/

Our solution included admin panel, where user can add a new entity, then Web App calls the Azure WebJob with some parameters. If you can implement that functionality inside your application (.exe one), then it should not be a problem. Be aware, however, and add static IP address to your virtual machine if you will use IP address in your solution.